# Photoshop scripting (javascript). Copying tiff files to template, changing text and saving. Looking to improve code

Tags: javascript, photoshop

I'm extremely new to scripting (this is one of my first scripts so please don't laugh too hard at how inefficient or weird it is).
I'm trying to have my script copy a tiff image into a template file, change the text in the template file and then save as using the name off the tiff files.  At which point it moves on the the next open tiff image and does the same.

It works, but I'm wondering if I can improve my code.

Particularly my if statement linking the file numbers to the text names is very lengthy and have a feeling that there is a better way to do this, but I'm not quite sure which direction to take.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
var dlg=  
"dialog{text:'Script Interface',bounds:[100,100,500,220],"+   
"txt_static:StaticText{bounds:[15,20,390,79] ,text:'Dont forget to change the PN and the SN of the template file first!! Click ok to continue, cancel to stop the script.', properties:{multiline:true}},"+
"btn_ok:Button{bounds:[10,80,190,101] , text:'ok' },"+ 
"btn_closedlg:Button{bounds:[210,80,390,101] , text:'Cancel' }};"  

var win = new Window(dlg,'PSD Creator');  

win.center();  

win.btn_ok.onClick = function() {   

    win.close(1);

    var doc = app.activeDocument;
    var openDoc = app.documents;
    var docNum = openDoc.length;

    //select tiff, select template, paste change text
    for (var i = 1; i < docNum; i++){   

        var layerNum = doc.layers.length

        app.activeDocument = app.documents[i]; // Select that document.

        //Tiff document name and its path after the new document is selected
        var setName = app.activeDocument.name;
        var setLenth = setName.length;
        var viewNumber = setName.slice (setLenth-8,setLenth-4);
        var tiffPath = app.activeDocument.path;
        //also document path name in order to use it as a file name
        var psdName = setName.substring (0,setLenth-19);

        app.activeDocument.selection.selectAll(); //select all
        app.activeDocument.selection.copy(); //copy;

        app.activeDocument = app.documents[0]; //select template
        app.activeDocument.activeLayer = app.activeDocument.layers["Layer 0"]; //select layer [0]
        app.activeDocument.paste();//paste


        //////////////////////////////////////
        //Changing the text inside the view //
        //////////////////////////////////////

        var textLayer = app.activeDocument.layers["VIEW TEXT"]//select layerset "VIEW TEXT"
        app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("VIEW TEXT").visible = true;                
        var x = viewNumber.toString();

            if (x == "0001") {
                app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("VIEW TEXT").textItem.contents = ("GL");
            }
            if (x == "0002") {
                app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("VIEW TEXT").textItem.contents = ("GL");
            }
            if (x == "0003") {
                app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("VIEW TEXT").textItem.contents = ("Z2 LF");
            }                   
            if (x == "0004") {
                app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("VIEW TEXT").textItem.contents = ("Z1 LA");
            }           
            if (x == "0005") {
                app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("VIEW TEXT").textItem.contents = ("Z3 LA");
            }
            if (x == "0006") {
                app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("VIEW TEXT").textItem.contents = ("Z4 RLF");
            }
            if (x == "0007") {
                app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("VIEW TEXT").textItem.contents = ("AL");
            }
            if (x == "0008") {
                app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("VIEW TEXT").textItem.contents = ("Z3 LF");
            }
            if (x == "0009") {
                app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("VIEW TEXT").textItem.contents = ("Z2 LF");
            }
            if (x == "0010") {
                app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("VIEW TEXT").textItem.contents = ("Z2 LA");
            }
            if (x == "0011") {
                app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("VIEW TEXT").textItem.contents = ("Z3 RLF");
            }
            if (x == "0012") {
                app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("VIEW TEXT").textItem.contents = ("CA");
            }
            if (x == "0013") {
                app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("VIEW TEXT").textItem.contents = ("Z4 LF");
            }
            if (x == "0014") {
                app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("VIEW TEXT").textItem.contents = ("Z4 RLA");

            }

            ////////
            //END //
            ////////


        var viewName = app.activeDocument.layers.getByName("VIEW TEXT").textItem.contents;

        function saveTemplate (name) {

            var file = new File(tiffPath + "/" + name + '.psd');
            var saveOptions = new PhotoshopSaveOptions();

            saveOptions.embedColorProfile = true;
            saveOptions.layers = true;

            doc.saveAs(file, saveOptions, true);
        }       

        saveTemplate(psdName + " " + viewName.toLowerCase());

        app.activeDocument.activeLayer.remove();

    }



}

win.show();
```

Comment: I might move this post to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh, am I posting this in the wrong place? Just to know for next time >.<

Comment: I would say yes Rebecca. It's fairly common to see these kind of questions on SO, just trying to make sure you get the best answer possible by using the correct site!

Comment: Ok! Good to know thanks!